# MySQl Query to select count until you hit a specific value

Tags: mysql

I have this table e.g.:

```
Id   StatusDate   Status
1    20-08-2014    
1    15-08-2014
1    09-08-2014     P
2    17-08-2014
1    10-08-2014
2    12-08-2014
2    06-07-2014     P
1    30-07-2014     
2    02-07-2014   
2    01-07-2014     P
```

...... and so on

I want to select count by ID where status is blank until I hit the first 'P' in ascending order of date group by ID. So my results will be like this.

```
ID    Count
1     3
2     2
```

Comment: Ascending order of date?

Comment: what about status 1 in second iteration

Comment: Count of 1 is 4 where status is blank. isn't it?

Comment: Ascending order of date @ Aziz.
Fixed count @ LearneR - thanks

Comment: ID 2 should have count 3 no?

Comment: @George no it should be 2 as the first 'P' was on 06-07-2014 so I should neglect any records no matter what their status is before this date.

Comment: so why id 1 have 4? closest `P` is on `09-08-2014`

Comment: @George right and fixed, even I got lost a bit ...

Comment: I think it's not right again? why 3? you should reglect status `P` right, so id 1 have count 2

Comment: No mate, 20, 15, and 10 august are counted until first p is hit on the 9th, everything behind no matter of its status P or blank is neglected (in our case 30th of july having status P)

Comment: I can see no correlation between the data set and the result set. You may have to walk us through that one again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table name is `StatusTable` This will work:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    COUNT(*) AS `Count` 
FROM StatusTable AS st 
WHERE 
    st.Status = ''
    AND st.StatusDate > (
        SELECT st2.StatusDate 
        FROM `StatusTable` AS st2 
        WHERE st.ID = st2.ID 
            AND st2.Status = 'P' 
        ORDER BY st2.StatusDate DESC 
        LIMIT 1
    ) 
GROUP BY st.ID
ORDER BY st.ID
```

Comment: Thanks George, this worked on my sample data, I will test it on my main table and will get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try it out. Not tested

```
SELECT t1.ID, count(*) FROM table t1 
WHERE t1.StatusDate >= (SELECT MAX(t2.StatusDate) FROM table t2 
                     WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID AND t2.Status = 'P') 
GROUP BY t1.ID
```

Comment: Thanks sarrus, tried it nut it returned an error: "Result of SELECT more than one row."

Comment: Edited my answer. Now subquery returns the highest StatusDate with speciefied ID and status

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a JOIN and COUNT rows which have a lower statusdate value, like this:

```
SELECT t1.id, SUM(CASE WHEN t1.statusdate > t2.statusdate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS mycount
FROM t t1 JOIN (
  SELECT id, MIN(statusdate) statusdate
  FROM t
  WHERE status = 'P'
  GROUP BY id
  ) t2
ON t1.id = t2.id 
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Working Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9d91/2

Comment: Thanks mate, but I got this error:
column statusdate not in table t2

Comment: @Moe that is strange because in my query statusdate is an alias: `MIN(statusdate) statusdate`

Comment: @Moe I have added a link in my answer which is a working demo of my query.